# How do I reset dotnetauth on the open id providers' sides?

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

Scenario:

1. I have 1@gmail.com, so I login on a site which features google login, like stackoverflow
2. stackoverflow bounces me over to google.com's login
3. when I login to google.com, I use 1@gmail.com and select the "remember me"
4. I'm back at stackoverflow, but I think, "I want to log out and use 2@gmail.com" instead
5. I log back out
6. I log back in, and it automatically logs me in as 1@gmail.com b/c I selected "remember me" in step 3. I don't even see the login on google.com that I saw in step 3

How can I tell Google, "stop remembering me!" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log in to your google account, then go [here](https://www.google.com/accounts/IssuedAuthSubTokens).

Alternatively, at google.com: My account -> Change authorized websites.

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically for the user?

Comment: You could do it for every user by changing the realm (or use per-user realm), but that's an ugly solution. There's no way to tell the provider "i don't want to be authorized anymore".